# How do I setup a Letsencrypt ssl on Xeams mail server?

Tags: email-server, java, openssl, lets-encrypt, keytool

First, I was able to successfully setup a letsencrypt certificate on an Ubuntu 14.0.4 server for my domain, and I  confirmed everything was okay, by verifying I could access my domain via https and checking that I really did have the correct files in:

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/`

I have a Xeams mail server running on the server and I've been finding it difficult following the steps in the [guide](http://www.xeams.com/usingssl.htm). First I had to convert the cert files generated by LetsEncrypt from `.pem` to `.crt` using:

`openssl x509 -outform der -in my-cert.pem -out my-cert.crt`

Which worked fine and converted the files successfully, but the problem I have with the guide is that, It assumes I don't already have an ssl certificate which isn't the case. I don't think I should have to generate a CSR code again when I already have the certificate from Letsencrypt.

To be clear, these are the cert files I have for my domain.

1. cert.pem
2. chain.pem
3. privkey.pem
4. fullchain.pem

But in the guide, it requires me generating CSR codes and whatnot, I have skipped generating a CSR to the part where I have to add the certificates to the keystore, but Its not very straightforward what I'm supposed to do, cause the files in the guide aren't correlating with what I have gotten from Letsencrypt.

When I try to follow the rest of the guide, and test that my server accepts connections on Secure IMAP port: 995 , my server returns a self signed certificate and not the certificate from the CA.

I used openssl to test the secure IMAP port 995

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:995`

I also confirmed Letsencrypt support for ssl email protocols and Java, so there has to be something I am not getting right. I have not been able to figure out how to add my certificates to the keystore.

Comment: https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm

Comment: http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2016/06/use-existing-ssl-certificate-linux-unifi-controller/

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out after days of searching thanks to the guide [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-the-certificate-for-tomcat/3677/9), you don't even need to use the keytool at all since xeams supports *PKCS12* certificates.

1. Create a *PKCS12* that contains your `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` :

   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out synametrics.cert -name xeams`
2. Copy your `synametrics.cert` to xeams' installation directory:

   `cp synametrics.cert /etc/Xeams/config/`
3. Create a `server.properties` file in the `./config` folder if it doesn't exist already and append the parameters below into the file:

   `javax.net.ssl.keyStore=config/synametrics.cert
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
   SSLCertificatePassword=password`

   Where *pasword* is the password you entered when you created the keystore with openssl.
4. Choose the *PKCS12* keystore type in Xeams admin panel > SMTP Configuration > Configure SSL:

   [image: Keystore parameters]
5. Enable the secure SMTP server and specify its port in xeams. Verify you can connect to your mail server on the specified ports:

   `openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:465`

---

**FIX FOR WEAK DH KEY**

6. You'll probably get an error from openssl about the *DHKey* used by xeams being too small, this is a xeams issue, not openssl or letsencrypt.

   The problem was caused by xeams using a very *weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key*, less than 1024 bits, when ideally, it shouldn't be less than 2048 bits.  I tried so many things but this is what fixed it for me:

   Update the jre that comes with xeams in `/etc/xeams/jre` with the ones in [this article](http://web.synametrics.com/Update-JRE.htm) by synammetrics:

   a. Stop the xeams smtp service:

   `service xeams stop`

   b. Rename the jre folder in your xeams insallation directory:

   `mv -T jre jre.old`

   c. Grab the compressed jre for your machine's architecture from the link to the article above and extract it to the `/etc/xeams/jre/` directory, your new jre folder should contain the contents of compressed jre.

   d. Start xeams!

   `service xeams start`

I hope this fixes it for someone out there. :)